# Remote Recording Devices over RDP

Tags: windows-10, audio, remote-desktop, audio-recording

Locally on a Windows 10 1511 computer I can view and change default playback and recording devices.  When I RDP to the same computer from another Windows 10 1609 comp, the devices are no longer available and only the remote audio is available and nothing is available under recording.  Is there a way to enable this so when I access the computer via RDP, I can customize the playback and recording devices to what is locally installed?

I am aware of changing the RDP advanced settings.  However, this does not give me the devices already installed locally to the remote computer.  The drivers in the Audio Inputs and Outputs in Device Manager are missing when RDP'd to the comp.  When I change the RDP session to leave the audio at the remote computer and then RDP, I am able to view all the devices but cannot use/hear them.

Any info would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This sounds like the problem I have. I want to remotely control a PC that has an audio capture card, but if I log in remotely, I can't see the audio capture device, only the RDP devices. I can see it if I turn off audio in the RDP client, but then I can't hear anything. IMHO The RDP audio devices should show as extra devices, not replace all the devices you have.

Answer (score 1):

The respondent https://superuser.com/a/1271060/1652417 probably does not know the problem and has apparently not tested his solution himself.

In Windows, during a Remote Desktop session, the ability to redirect the audio output of the physical card to the virtual "Remote Audio" card is missing. You can only use either a physical card and not listen to it remotely, or use Remote Audio and no access to a physical sound card. I only know of paid software that solves this problem, e.g. [www.TeamViewer.com](http://www.TeamViewer.com).

Answer (score -1):

Open **Run**, type “***services.msc***” end with enter to open Services. Make sure below service is running, and Startup type is configured as Automatic:
**Remote Desktop Services UserMode Port Redirector**

Please re-start both local and remote system in **Clean Boot**. Then, open **Run**, type “***mstsc***” to open Remote Desktop Connection. Select Local Resources – Remote audio – Settings - Remote Audio Playback configured with 'Play on this computer' – Remote Audio Recording configured with ‘Record from this computer’.

Besides, you may also try to open Run, type “***mstsc /admin***” to open Remote Desktop Connection and check the result.

If possible, please try remote desktop connection from any other device, or, using different RDP client(such as **Microsoft Remote Desktop** on Windows Store - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/microsoft-remote-desktop/9wzdncrfj3ps) to confirm that if it is specific OS, or specific software relate problem.

Comment: Doesn't change anything